# Flutter: How to prevent banner ad from showing if view is already disposed

Tags: dart, admob, flutter

I am currently experimenting with banner ads from the firebase_admob plugin. The process to show and dispose them is pretty straightforward, I do it in initState() and dispose().

The code to create and display the add looks like this:

```
_bannerAd = createBannerAd();
_bannerAd
  ..load().then((loaded) {
    if (loaded) {
      _bannerAd..show();
    }
  });
```

However, as I am calling show() asynchronously, it is possible that the view was already closed when the ad is being shown (i.e. by clicking back button really fast). In that case, the dispose() method will never be called and the ad will be "stuck" on the bottom of the screen.

How can I solve this problem? Am I using the banner ad wrong or is it possible to detect if the view was already changed? I tried using the "mounted" property of the state but it didn't seem to work.

Comment: this is a great [full example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r9wbxYE2DYY)

Comment: Yes, from a quick look this example is subject to exactly the type of problem I am describing here.

Comment: glad to hear that

Comment: @areiser when you tried using "mounted" what was the issue, was it always true or something?

Comment: yes, mounted seemed to always be true, even if the ad was displayed after the view was changed.

Comment: are you using navigator?

Comment: @Tree Yes, I am using Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(new PageRouteBuilder(...))) if that matters.

Comment: yes it matters as the tree remains alive I believe in navigator. so It doesnt get called dispose. Maybe that will help.

Comment: You can disable back key in appbar until you load the banner, that should be the easiest way. (also disable back key on android)

Comment: Interesting, I'll read up on this. Thanks for the hint!

Answer (score 1):

Just check "this.mounted" property of state class before showing the add.

```
    _bannerAd = createBannerAd();
    _bannerAd
  ..load().then((loaded) {
    if (loaded && this.mounted) {
      _bannerAd..show();
    }
  });
```

Comment: what is the value of mounted variable.

Comment: Its an inbuilt property of stateful widgets.

Comment: No property found in stateful widget.

Comment: Sorry I mean its property of state class. https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/State/mounted.html
Did you try out it in actual code before setState call?

Answer (score 0):

From https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/21474#issuecomment-535188820, that's a little hack but it works for me.

You can add a little delay in your dispose method like this:

```
static void hideBannerAd() {
  Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 500), () {
    if (_bannerAd != null) _bannerAd.dispose();
    _bannerAd = null;
  });
}
```

500 milliseconds is enough.